# How to lock a single view to portrait only in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor mobile website

Tags: jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, screen-orientation

Is it possible and if so then how can I lock a specific view to only use either portrait or landscape orientation in an ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor mobile website that uses JQuery and JQueryMobile? For example, all views can have a portrait or landscape view but I want one view to only be viewable in portrait mode such that any orientation changes will not affect the view.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After see some posts, I found only possible solution but is it not possible to iOS apps.

I think that you want something like the solution of that post [jQuery Mobile lock orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010010/1853864)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After a lot of reading I do not think there is currently a good way to do this but at this link http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/24433282939/mobile-safari-wishlist-what-devs-want-this they talk about it being in the works and they suggest a workaround using css transforms and media queries. I think it is for the entire site though. Either way I found a solution to my original problem and here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710834/problems-with-mobiscroll-orientationchange-and-access-address-bar-crashes-some. I will leave this unanswered for now.